# MX Google Maps fieldtype problem

Tags: upgrade, updating, mx-google-map

I'm updating a site from ExpressionEngine 2.1.1 to 2.8.1. The previous version of MX Google Maps was 1.0b I've installed version 1.5.3.140526

The exp_fieldtypes table shows version 1.0b installed but if I check the Fieldtypes page in ExpressionEngine it shows 1.5.3.140526 as the version. When I click on the fieldtype I get 2 PHP errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Mx_google_map_ft' does not have a method 'display_global_settings'
Filename: api/Api_channel_fields.php
Line Number: 397
```

and

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/Josh/Sites/website/webroot/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 446
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My apology - looks like with one of update I missed procedure for version <1.3.4. It is no more global settings in MX Google Map (most of them was replaced with ee config.php varibles). I will add this update function in next  build.

Right now you can just run next query

```
update exp_fieldtypes SET has_global_settings = 'n' WHERE name = 'mx_google_map'
```

You can do this directly in EE CP -> tools -> data -> sql man

Comment: Max, Thanks. I ran that query and it got me over that hump. When I go to Channel Fields > Edit Field I get other PHP errors:
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: max_points
Filename: mx_google_map/ft.mx_google_map.php
Line Number: 560
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: icon
Filename: mx_google_map/ft.mx_google_map.php
Line Number: 561
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: slide_bar
Filename: mx_google_map/ft.mx_google_map.php
Line Number: 562

Comment: ...and

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/Josh/Sites/website/webroot/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 446